# How to show particular format of date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How do I show datetime format like `Monday, February 18, 2013 10:52` in my HTML page using Javascript Date Function?

Update:

I am trying

```
var d=new Date();
var n=d.toString();
document.write(n);
```

But I want time should be automatically updated not on page refresh. Do I need to use AJAX?

Comment: See new Date().toString();

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_date.asp

This is mostly where you want it. From there, I would just do some regex to modify it to get what you want.

Comment: [Date objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5) have functions like `getFullYear`, `getMonth`, `getDate` and so on that you can use to create a formatted date string. Or you can just accept what the browser provides using `toString` or `toLocaleString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using following code to show date in my desired format

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function makeArray() 
                {
                    for (i = 0; i<makeArray.arguments.length; i++)
                    this[i + 1] = makeArray.arguments[i];
                }

                var months = new makeArray('January','February','March','April','May',
                'June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
                var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
                var date = new Date();
                var day = date.getDate();
                var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                var yy = date.getYear();
                var year = (yy < 1000) ? yy + 1900 : yy;
                var hours = date.getHours();
                var minutes = date.getMinutes();
                document.write(days[ date.getDay() ] + ", " + months[month] + " " + day + ", " + year + " " + hours +": " + minutes);
            </script>
```

Comment: Why would you use `makeArray` instead of just using a literal like you do with `days`? Just make the first value `null` or something.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out :- http://jsfiddle.net/2Fj7m/

And the date and time will update automatically.

HTML:-

```
<body onload="startTime()">
    <div id="txt" ></div>
</body>
```

JS:-

```
var months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May',
    'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
var days = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');

function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    var weekday = days[today.getDay()];
    var month = months[today.getMonth()];
    var year = today.getFullYear();
    day = today.getUTCDate();

    // add a zero in front of numbers<10

    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =weekday + ", " +month +" "+ day+", " + year+ " "+ h + ":" + m;
    t = setTimeout(function () {
        startTime()
    }, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery loaded, you can do:

HTML:

```
<div id='date'/>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#date').append(Date().toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a javascript debugger as firebug or chrome's debugger, which will show you all the native javascript functions available.

You can use

```
var myDate = new Date();

myDate.toLocaleFormat();
```

OR

```
myDate.toLocaleString();
```

both of which will give

```
Monday, 18 February, 2013 10:57:46 AM
```

which is close to the format you have mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can create this format using `.Date()` function in javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var monthNames = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

      var dayNames = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");

      var today = new Date();
      var cDay = today.getDay();
      var cDate = today.getDate();
      var cMonth = today.getMonth();
      var cYear = today.getFullYear();

      var cHour = today.getHours();
      var cMin = today.getMinutes();
      var cSec = today.getSeconds();


      alert(dayNames[cDay]+ "," + " "+ monthNames[cMonth] + " " +cDate  + "," +cYear + " " +cHour+ ":" + cMin+ ":" +cSec );
});
```